Getting LastRunDate of a specific automation via API
I'm trying to get LastRunDate of a specific automation using REST API GET
/automation/v1/automations/{id} (Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_automation_studio_automations?meta=Get%2Ba%2Bspecific%2Bautomation)
I'm able to get the details just fine using Postman. However, when I tried using SSJS both in Automation Studio and CloudPage I got an error.
Here's the snippet of the code in CloudPage:
var automationId = "abc"
var restUrl = "https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/";
var endpoint = restUrl + 'automation/v1/automations/' + automationId;
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
var result;
  try {
            var response = HTTP.Get(endpoint, headerNames, headerValues);
            //result = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Response[0]);
            Write(stringify(response));
        } catch (e) {
            Write("Failed to fetch automation details for ID: " + automationId + "\n" + Stringify(e));
        }

Here's the result I got after publishing the page:
Failed to fetch automation details for ID: abc
{"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPGet function call.  
See inner exception for details.
 ClientID: 123
  JobID: 0
  ListID: 0
  BatchID: 0
  SubscriberID: 0
URL: https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/abc",
"description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPGet function call.  See inner exception for details.
 ClientID: 123
  JobID: 0
  ListID: 0
 BatchID: 0
  SubscriberID: 0
 URL: https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/abc
  Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR
 - from Jint --> 

 --- inner exception 1---

ExactTarget.OMM.OMMException: An exception occurred when attempting to retrieve content by a HttpGet call.  URL: https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/abc
  Error Code: HTTP_WB_RTV
 - from OMMCommon --> 

 --- inner exception 2---

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. - from System"}

I've tried to find out about error code: HTTP_WB_RTV but nothing useful came up. I also tried using Platform.Function.HTTPGet() but that got "Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame" error.  So if anyone has an idea on how to resolve this error. I'd really appreciate your help! Thanks!

You could use the AutomationInstance data view, https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mktg.mc_as_data_view_automation_instance.htm&type=5

Can you try to change from Write(stringify(response)); to Write(Stringify(response)); to see if the error still happens?

@SwatiMishra I'm trying to get automations where last run date is way beyond 30 days so the data views won't work for me unfortunately.

@DucLe The error still happens. In automation studio, I just keep the value in response without writing anywhere and it still went to catch.

You can try this. It works for me:
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

var automationId = "Your Automation ID";
var endpoint = "https://SubDomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/" + automationId;
var accessToken = "YOUR ACCESS TOKEN";
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
try{

var response = HTTP.Get(endpoint, headerNames, headerValues);
Write(response.Content);

} catch(ex){
    Write(Stringify(ex));
}
</script>

I doubt there is something else in your code that you didn't show us that is causing the issue.
Speaking of _automationinstance data view, it's interesting to me since I thought the data retention period for this data view would be 6 months, but it seems not. It doesn't work with my automation which has not run beyond 30 days either.
